# Formidable module in node not supporting languages other than English

Tags: node.js, formidable

There is a html form that takes data from User in English and Malayalam language.  I am using ajax to post the data to a node route.  I am using formidable module to parse the form fields, when trying to log the field values the data in English displayed without any issue, but the data in Malayalam is displayed as ?????? ???.

Are there any modules for that or any other solution is present.

Comment: Field is a text field or file upload?

Comment: It's a text field, @notionquest

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer

```
[base64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-base64) 

[fiddle]    (https://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/qaght/)
```